# UILongPressGesture in iphone sdk

Tags: iphone

```
 UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPressOnUndoGesture = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] 
    initWithTarget:self 
    action:@selector(handleLongPressOnUndoGesture:)];
    [longPressOnUndoGesture setMinimumPressDuration:2.0];
    [longPressOnUndoGesture release];
```

i have the above code to deasctivate the autoscroll timer in my applicationthis is the function for this.

```
-(void) handleLongPressOnUndoGesture:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer*)recognizer {
    [autoscrollTimer invalidate];

}
```

but when i taptohold for 2 seconds it wont stop the timer.is there any error in my code for gesture.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not using the gesture recognizer, as you release it immediately as you created it. You have to attach it to a view like this:

```
UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPressOnUndoGesture = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] 
initWithTarget:self 
action:@selector(handleLongPressOnUndoGesture:)];
[longPressOnUndoGesture setMinimumPressDuration:2.0];

// TRICK HERE
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:longPressUndoGesture];

[longPressOnUndoGesture release];
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that you are not adding the gesture recognizer to the view it should work upon:

```
[self.view addGestureRecognizer: longPressOnUndoGesture];
```

(if `self` is your controller).